# How can one "scan" a lambda expression in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

Is is possible to scan a function provided as a lamba expression to figure out the nature of the function at runtime?

Example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Examples example = new Examples(x => x ^ 2 + 2);
    }
}

public class Examples
{
    public Examples(Func<dynamic, dynamic> func)
    {
        // How can I scan "func" here to figure out that it is defined as "x => x ^ 2 + 2" instead of, say, as "x => Math.Exp(x)"?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx), like this:

```
public Examples(Expression<Func<dynamic, dynamic>> func) {
    ...
}
```

For more information, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is an expression tree, you could change your Example method signature to....

```
public Examples(Expression<Func<dynamic, dynamic>> exp)
{
  // Visit the expression in here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can examine the syntactical structure of a [LambdaExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.aspx) by looking at the Parameters property and Body property. The Body is an Expression node representing the root of the function body's abstract syntax tree.

or use an [ExpressionVisitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor%28VS.100%29.aspx), which traverses the nodes in the expression tree. Example code here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Basically you wrap your `Func<>` type inside an `Expression<>` type and use its properties to parse it.